# How to pass anti-forgery state to the Google Sign-In button or javascript?

Tags: python, google-plus

I'm following this tutorial to create a sign-in button.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

But I don't see how the anti-forgery state is passed to the button snippet (step 4).

Should there be a parameter like data-state for the button?

The whole tutorial doesn't mention how the state code is passed from the page to google server and back to my signInCallback function.

```
<div id="signinButton">
  <span class="g-signin"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
        data-clientid="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
        data-redirecturi="postmessage"
        data-accesstype="offline"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-callback="signInCallback">
  </span>
</div>
```

Then in step 6, I don't see how the state is passed to the ajax server call.  So how does this if-condition work in step 7?

> if request.args.get('state', '') != session['state']:

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 8):

After a little poking around, I found that there's an undocumented parameter, data-state, for the button.  Once I set it, I could it coming back to my callback function.

```
<div id="signinButton">
  <span class="g-signin"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
        data-clientid="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
        data-state="MY_STATE" <!-- The state is sent to Google and back to my callback -->
        data-redirecturi="postmessage"
        data-accesstype="offline"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-callback="signInCallback">
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The state ends up being a value stored in the session variable. Sessions are usually represented as session cookies, which are random themselves. The session cookie is automatically sent along with the ajax request, so there is nothing specific that you have to do. I'm not sure if PHP puts the state code in a cookie directly or uses a session cookie to track the session, but either way should be equally effective. The whole point of the anti-forgery code is just to make sure someone can't do a blind attack against your server.

You'll note that this has nothing to do with the button itself. You don't need to send it to Google, and Google doesn't want it. This is simply between your server and the page it is displaying.

Comment: The state token needs to be generated from my backend, stored in the session, passed to the Google for oauth, and ultimately sent back to my js callback function and my backend for verification.  That's show the anti-forgery state token works, from what I understand.  If Google doesn't pass me the state token, I wouldn't know the callback is legit because anyone can create a fake out to my backend to create fake users and I would have no way to verify the data.

Comment: Right, but you don't need to send it to Google (although you can). The page itself still has the state token which it can pass on to the server, or you can use the session token itself. The callback function already has has the state since the page has the state.